# c# service: I am unable to pass a pass a parameter on service startup

Tags: c#

I am writing an c# services in VS 2015 and I need to pass a parameter when the service starts. I entered the parameter like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NBFP.png)

and my code in the service looks like this

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
   try
   {
       base.OnStart(args);
       WriteToFile("args = " + args[0].ToString());
```

When I start the services I get the following error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" which tells me that the argument is not read. Where am I going wrong.

thanks;

Comment: Here is more of the code. I am not sure if its necessary.
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

           System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            try
            {
                base.OnStart(args);
                WriteToFile("args = " + args[0].ToString());

Comment: That argument is passed to main not OnStart. OnStart arguments are configured elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to know is that a process can contain more than one service.

The arguments passed to `Main` are typically used to instruct the process to do things like install itself, uninstall itself, perform maintenance tasks, or enter the service control loop (i.e. to call `ServiceBase.Run`).

The arguments passed to `OnStart` on the other hand come from the Service Control Manager, not from the command line. They are typically used to instruct the process which process to start (if there is  more than one service managed by the process).

The `Main` parameters are configured as part of the "path to executable".

The `OnStart` parameters are configured as "Start parameters" in the service settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments otherwise args[0] is null .. in debug mode goto project settings pass the build arguments,check how it's working